# Windows 10 installaton USBs sold by Microsoft

Tags: windows, usb

With the recent release of Microsoft's Windows 10, I dropped by a local Microsoft store to purchase a windows 10 installation media.

To my surprise (somewhat) the employees said that they do not offer windows 10 DVDs in their stores and that the only thing they offered was windows 10 USBs.

I have a few very simple questions that the employees there failed to answer so I'm hoping that you will be able to heIp me on this.

1. My first concern was whether the USB was write protected -- so if plugged into an infected computer could a virus corrupt the media. I'm currently running on linux mint, I tried to copy a test text file to the root directory but that failed with "Access denied" error. Some of the permissions on a few folders were dxrw .. please excuse my lack of knowledge on this but since I was not able to copy any files to the root folder, I should not be able to alter any of the folders that have dxrw permission, right??
2. I've found some tutorials online demonstrating how to bypass the write protection on USBs so how reliable is the write protection Microsoft implemented on their USBs?
3. Would you say the USBs write protection is software or hardware level? .. And which of the two are more reliable? I would assume the latter?
4. Would I be better off with a DVD installation media? Are the "risks" of a write only USB vs ready only DVD the same?

Please excuse my paranoia and lack of knowledge on these types of things, I just feel more comfortable with DVD-ROM installation media as I've always relied on them for clean installations.

Comment: you can also buy ON-LINE version of Windows 10 with Digital License to install into your system - but this option become "attached" to your device and cannot be migrated to another system if you upgrade your hardware. you can upgrade hard disk or memory or both but not more ( by example - processor ). and by the way - you also can convert ESD file generated by install process after upgrade to ISO and burn your own DVD - then you can verify hash numbers to check integrity and non modify digital image of original version. search hash of many version in MSDN site. Good Luck !

Comment: Can you please edit your post to clarify, and please limit the post to 1 question.